# Broadcast receiver added inside onCreate() of foreground service not working

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Broadcast receiver class inside the service

```
  inner class ServiceNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
            val action = intent!!.action
            Util.log("action from foreground services")
            when (action) {
                FOREGROUND_NEXT -> {
                    next()
                }
                FOREGROUND_PREVIOUS -> {
                    prevoius()
                }
                FOREGROUND_PLAY_PAUSE -> {
                    if (exoPlayer.isPlaying) {
                        pause()
                    } else {
                        play()
                    }
                }
                FOREGROUND_STOP -> {
                    stopSelf()
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am registering it inside the onCreate() of the service like so

```
  serviceNotificationListener = ServiceNotificationReceiver()

        val intentfliter = IntentFilter().apply {
            addAction(FOREGROUND_PLAY_PAUSE)
            addAction(FOREGROUND_PREVIOUS)
            addAction(FOREGROUND_NEXT)
            addAction(FOREGROUND_STOP)
        }
        this.registerReceiver(serviceNotificationListener, intentfliter)
```

The pending intent

```
playintent = Intent(this, ServiceNotificationReceiver::class.java).setAction(
        FOREGROUND_PLAY_PAUSE
    )

    playpendingIntent =
        PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, playintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
```

I am adding it as an action inside the notification builder like so

```
  addAction(
                com.google.android.exoplayer2.R.drawable.exo_icon_previous,
                "Previous",
                previouspendingIntent
            )
```

However the clicks are not registering inside the service. I cannot add it in the manifest due to some complexity in the app and this is the only way. So what could be the issue. Is it the flags or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting your intent target component to `yourpackage.YourService.ServiceNotificationReceiver` which is not registered in manifest, system will not be able to resolve it and nothing is executed.

Modify your intent to target only your apps package then your receiver will be able to match it:

```
playintent = Intent().setPackage(this.packageName).setAction(FOREGROUND_PLAY_PAUSE)
```

Comment: I am registering it here
  `this.registerReceiver(serviceNotificationListener, intentfliter)`

Comment: When system is resolving target component it only looks through manifest, your runtime receiver class doesn't matter in that case.

Comment: what does the registerReceiver method do? it is not deprecated as far as the ide is concerned

Comment: Your intent is targeting an app component (which are static classes/entry points declared in the manifest). Receivers registered at runtime are not considered app components so intents cannot target them explicitly, you can at most target package and use unique actions.

Comment: Thanks but I was able to do it by putting the action string inside the Intent like this Intent(FOREGROUND_PLAY_PAUSE)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Sorry that it took me a while to understand